# How to format a date submission value of a webform?

Tags: webforms, tokens

I need to format a birthday submission value to the short format (01.01.2015) defined under admin/config/regional/date-time on a webform.

This Token is working but it uses the long format (Fr, 01/01/2015):

```
[submission:values:bday]
```

I tried the following token variations :

```
[submission:values:bday:short]  
[submission:values:bday:custom:short]
[submission:values:bday:custom:d.m.Y] 
[submission:values:bday:date:short]
```

But none of them submits my desired output. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a answer myself.
Instead of changing the date format tokens you can set the date format globally for webforms under admin/config/content/webform.

Answer (score 0):

You could change it server side with a datetimeformatter or client side. Also if you'd like these kind of things often, you can take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)